# Flutter web: google map

Tags: google-maps, flutter-web

I want to display bunch of locations on google map on flutter web.
I've done the same for android using the plug-in: google_maps_flutter
For the web Found the plug-in:

google_maps_flutter_web

But the example in the plug-in description is not useful.
My code for the android is not even compiling for the google_maps_flutter_web when I include

```
import 'package:google_maps_flutter_web/google_maps_flutter_web.dart';
```

Without normal include it is giving run time error

```
import 'package:google_maps_flutter_web/google_maps_flutter.dart';
```

Can someone please point to some code example to display list of locations on google map on flutter web?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting run time error for my google_maps_flutter

> The following UnimplementedError was thrown building GoogleMap(dirty,
> dependencies: [Directionality], state: _GoogleMapState#5b0ef):
> buildView() has not been implemented.

I found out the reason. The root cause of the error was version of my imported plug-in google_maps_flutter was older than the google_maps_flutter_web plug-in.

When I set the version of both these plug-ins to the latest version the code started working.